# docker-jenkins container can't access internet

Tags: docker, jenkins, containers

I installed jenkins container on docekr.

I used docker-compose with yml file.

```
version: '2'
    services:
      jenkins:
        image: 'bitnami/jenkins:2'
        ports:
          - '8080:8080'
          - '8443:8443'
          - '50000:50000'
        volumes:
          - 'jenkins_data:/bitnami/jenkins'
        dns:
          - '8.8.8.8'
          - '1.1.1.1'
    volumes:
      jenkins_data:
        driver: local
```

In logs, i found UnknownHostException error.

```
    jenkins_1  | 2020-03-23 17:45:06.490+0000 [id=46]       INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: The attempt #1 to do the action check updates server failed with an allowed exception:
    jenkins_1  | java.net.UnknownHostException: updates.jenkins.io
...
    jenkins_1  | 2020-03-23 17:45:06.490+0000 [id=46]       INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Calling the listener of the allowed exception 'updates.jenkins.io' at the attempt #1 to do the action check updates server
    jenkins_1  | 2020-03-23 17:45:06.492+0000 [id=46]       INFO    hudson.util.Retrier#start: Attempted the action check updates server for 1 time(s) with no success
```

I tried to resolve this error. But failed finally.

1. set 'dns' parameter.

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 1.1.1.1
   ```
2. reset bridge network.

   ```
   systemctl stop docker
   iptables -t nat -F
   ifconfig docker0 down
   brctl delbr docker0
   systemctl start docker
   ```
3. test ping

   ```
   docker run -it bitnami/jenkins:2 ping 8.8.8.8
   ```

   > [FATAL tini (8)] exec ping failed: No such file or directory

   ```
   docker run -it ubuntu:trusty ping 8.8.8.8
   ```

   > PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8:
   >   icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=31.3 ms 64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2
   >   ttl=52 time=30.8 ms

   ```
   docker run -it ubuntu:trusty ping google.com
   ```

   > ping: unknown host google.com

I think bitnami/jenkins maybe doesn't include ping.

Maybe It's not problem about bridge because of Test case 3.

I don't know what should I check.

Can you give me some hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are only exposing your ports on loopback interface. Change your ports declaration from

```
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8443:8443'
      - '50000:50000'
```

to

```
    ports:
      - '0.0.0.0:8080:8080'
      - '0.0.0.0:8443:8443'
      - '0.0.0.0:50000:50000'
```

To allow accessing those ports on all interfaces (i.e. including from outside the host).

Comment: thank you for your answer. i tried this. but problem wasn't resolved.

Comment: That's what I get for reading the first half of the question and jumping on the first thing that looked wrong. You're asking about *outgoing* connections, and I answered for *incoming* connections. Sorry about that. I don't see anything wrong with the compose config for outgoing, so the underlying problem is probably with iptables or other firewall on your Docker host.

Comment: Thank you. I will check my firewall and iptables again!